# Stringify nested array of object using java script to pass as a parameter in a url

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have a nested JSON array of object. I want pass it as a param in URL want to save it to the Mongo db. But it when i did that it it saved as [object object]. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi! Please show what you are doing exactly, the input and the expected output. Also, consider that a url is used to pass parameters for a *query*, not to post data. Use HTTP POST instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have any object.Than you have passed this object in params like this.you cannot send any object because URL not known about what type of you sending any key.so first we have convert object to string.than you can send any nested object.

```
  var add={
        name:"abc",
        college:{
            id:3
        }
    }
var key = JSON.stringify(add);
   const request = require('request');   
  request(' http://localhost:8080/user/send/'+ key, function(err, res, body) {  
            console.log(body);
        });
```

Than your server side code like this for access to req api.

```
app.get('/send/:key', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.params.key)
//{"name":"abc","college":{"id":3}}   you easily access object like this

    });
```

Comment: When I stringfy Json array and pass it in the mongo db it shows error. I have array of array json object

Comment: [
    {   
        "id":"5922652f86b53b2f494a31f9",
        "name":"Green Handbag",
        "qty":1,
        "sku":"1111",
        "totWeight":null,
        "price":"350",
        "total":"350",
        "imgURL":[
            {
            "img":"16.JPG",
            "$$hashKey":"object:1102"
            }
        ],
        "totalQty":347,
        "$$hashKey":"object:1108"

    }

]
this is my json string.

Comment: when you get json array from (req.params.key).than before store mongodb you have to JSON.parse(req.params.key) first.after all you can saved your json document in mongodb

Comment: error  is showing because I think you are saving  json in string format.so before saving you have to first parse of json afterall you can saved.

Comment: Thank You all for your replies.